# Implicit Lang in field constructors

Tags: scala, playframework, internationalization, playframework-2.2

In a Play Framework 2.2.1 application, I have a [custom field constructor](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaCustomFieldConstructors) like this:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

<div class="form-group @if(elements.hasErrors) {has-error}">
  <label for="@elements.id" class="control-label">@elements.label</label>
  @if(elements.input.toString().contains("class=")) {
    @Html(elements.input.toString().replaceFirst("(class=[\"'])", "$1form-control "))
  } else {
    @Html(elements.input.toString().replaceFirst("(<\\w+ )", "$1class=\"form-control\" "))
  }
  @if(!elements.infos.isEmpty) { <p class="help-block text-muted">@elements.infos(elements.lang).mkString("; ")</p> }
  @if(!elements.errors.isEmpty) { <p class="help-block">@elements.errors(elements.lang).mkString("; ")</p> }
</div>
```

And I reference it from a template like this:

```
@()(implicit lang: Lang)
@implicitFieldConstructor = @{ FieldConstructor(views.html.helpers.fieldConstructor.f) }
```

Everything works, including localization.

The question is: how can I avoid having to explicitly pass `elements.lang` to `infos()` and `errors()`?

If I add an implicit Lang parameter to the field constructor like this:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)(implicit lang: Lang)
```

then I get this compilation error at the reference in the other template:

```
type mismatch;
found   : views.html.helper.FieldElements => (play.api.i18n.Lang => play.api.templates.HtmlFormat.Appendable)
required: views.html.helper.FieldElements => play.api.templates.Html
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `FieldConstructor` method that you try to call with your field constructor expects a one parameter function but now you give it a multi parameter list one, that is what the type mismatch in your error says.

Maybe you could provide the implicit parameter beforehand using implicitly[Lang], something like

```
@implicitFieldConstructor = @{ 
  FieldConstructor(views.html.helpers.fieldConstructor.f(_)(implicitly[Lang]) 
}
```